# Where do I find an up-to-date version of boost?

Tags: c++

Where can I find up-to-date packages for boost on Maverick/Natty/Oneiric/Precise?

Ideally, I would like the latest 1.47.0 and be able to update that to the next release when it comes out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~jkeiren/+archive/ppa has a no-change backport of boost1.48. You should be able to upgrade to Precise while using that PPA.

Answer (score 4):

Using the packages in the standard repositories is the recommended way to ensure that you have both a stable system and also be supported through an upgrade to the next Ubuntu release.

You can install extra testing repositories - called PPA's.  These are available through launchpad and should really be used for testing new software.

One such PPA I found is this one by [Daniel Pfeifer](https://launchpad.net/~purplekarrot/+archive/ppa).

Please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87306/how-to-install-libboost-1-48) which explains the purpose of the PPA from its author.

You should note - some people have found several issues with the use of this PPA.  As such, you should perhaps consider [compiling boost yourself](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) using the linked step-by-step guide

**To Install from PPA**

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:purplekarrot/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**To Remove**

I would remove the PPA before attempting to upgrade to the next version of Ubuntu:

```
ppa-purge ppa:purplekarrot/ppa
```

Comment: +1 if only for clear instructions.  However, adding this ppa makes my system fall into dependency hell and many many error codes.  My advise is: do not use it.

Comment: I had a similar experience, but people seem to be able to use it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605754/building-boost-on-linux

Comment: It works pretty well for me. Except that the results files libboost_* end with the (old?) convention of having the '-mt' at the end of the name. So now I have to link to, for example, -lboost_regex-mt. I wish there were a sort of pkg-config for boost.

Comment: other problems: as described here, http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/08/170234.php the provided library is not compiled with c++0x, so some functions calls (notably boost::filesystem::copy_file) will not compile if you use c++0x.

Comment: @fossfreedom When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` [no boost files are listed to being upgraded](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87306/how-to-install-libboost-1-48). I use Maverick and have Boost 1.42 installed.

Comment: I want to **discourage everybody from using `ppa:purplekarrot`** since it's purpose is odd as [stated by Daniel Pfeiffer](http://askubuntu.com/a/94842/18533)!

Answer (score 1):

Note that many Boost libraries are header only, so you may be able to get away with just downloading the Boost tarball and including what you need.

Comment: Sadly I do need threading and a few others that are not header only.  ^_~  thanks nonetheless, a good answer.

Comment: Oh well.  Just as a last mention, I've been using boost_thread a lot lately across versions and don't see a lot of difference from 1.40 to 1.47.