# How to install libboost 1.48?

Tags: 10.10, apt, ppa, c++

I would like to install the latest [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org/) onto my 10.10 system using a PPA but cannot find one that works. [Nordlöw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683710/nordlow) already [suggested good sources in a similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605754/building-boost-on-linux/6617896) but I could not install the library. The installer states that I have the latest version running.

The `ppa:purplekarrot` by [Daniel Pfeiffer](https://launchpad.net/~purplekarrot/+archive/ppa) does not upgrade my current 1.42 installation. [image: current 1.42 installation]

Although I try to follow the [exact instructions by fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61384/where-do-i-find-an-up-to-date-version-of-boost) there are no packages listed to being upgraded when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Here is the [output log](http://pastebin.com/ZsWeXTbE).

When I try to install `libboost-filesystem` the only tab completions I am offered are the following.

```
⚡ sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem
libboost-filesystem1.40.0    libboost-filesystem1.42.0    libboost-filesystem-dev
libboost-filesystem1.40-dev  libboost-filesystem1.42-dev
```

Comment: similar question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/61384/where-do-i-find-an-up-to-date-version-of-boost

Comment: ... still need to see the update and upgrade output - can you pastebin the results please?

Comment: It was not ticked. Here is the [latest installation output](http://pastebin.com/QN2ZEnxD). Should I uninstall boost 1.42 before?

Comment: Why do the packages not have the signature 1.48 but 111111-maverick.

Comment: that's the naming convention the PPA maintainer has used.  For some reason libboost-filesystem-dev has been kept back - what happens if you just install this package ie. `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev` ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. So I run `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev` without running `sudo apt-get upgrade` (right?). The installation starts but cannot resolve all dependencies. Here is the partial log I could catch: http://pastebin.com/VwWM7mzs

Comment: from the trace it looks like you have the very same issue as the OP to the question I answered.  Strange - since other commenters said the PPA works ok.  I would ppa-purge that PPA.  Maybe there is another PPA?  otherwise the only solutions I can think of is to compile from source or to look to upgrading/dual booting with a newer version of ubuntu.

Comment: Hm. Thank you. How to think about `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`? Does this update my Ubuntu 10.10 to something > 10.10?

Comment: Using Upgrade Manager to upgrade is easier... it will go to 11.04.  However - take an image backup first - you've got lots of PPAs that could muck-up an upgrade.

Comment: Oh! --- I tried sth else: I uninstalled all libboost packages (1.42 in my case). Then I installed libboost-filesystem `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem`. That worked. Here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/jYKsV7LW). --- But: Since it is for the purpose to install [Gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) I am still stucked. When I run ./configure --with-tinyxml the installer stops because it could not find boost >= 1.46... Here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/uYbKs12x). Do you know how I can deal with this?

Comment: I got the same issue with Ubuntu Desktop 11.04 64-bit

Comment: In case you want to install Gource I figured out what needs to be done to fulfill the dependencies. This [post on GLM](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31441/how-and-where-to-install-a-headers-only-library) answers one issue. For Boost you need to customize some more settings. If you are interested please open another question and I will explain the details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I **did not use the PPA** since the author clearified its purpose.

> please note that the Boost packages in my PPA are not based on the
>   official 1.48 release of boost.
>
> We are developing a new CMake-based build system for the Boost C++
>   Libraries that can create component-based installers.
>
> My PPA currently is used for testing whether the package generation
>   using our new build system is working. Whether the generated packages
>   are working is currently not tested. If you are looking for a stable
>   Boost release, you should not use this PPA.
>
> I suggest you [compile boost yourself](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install). It is actually quite easy.
>   You don't need to call install and you don't need admin rights. Just
>   download the boost sources, exctract them and in a terminal window
>   call:
>
> $ ./bootstrap.sh $
>   ./b2
>
> Then set the BOOST_ROOT environment variable to the path where you
>   extracted boost. You now should be able to build Gource.

Nevertheless, there are some details that I needed to take care of regarding Gource. I will post them in a short while since I need to look them up again.